# How to create a deterministic uniqueidentifier (GUID) from an integer value

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid

*Note: This is not about database design nor about the general use of a GUID. This is about deterministically create such GUID's for test data, on a Microsoft SQL server.*

We are migrating our database away from integer identifiers to the uniqueidentifier data type.

**For test purposes we want to migrate our test data sets to known GUID values, deterministically based on our former integer values**

```
UPDATE Unit
SET UnitGuid = NEWID(UnitId)
```

Obviously this does not work right away. **How to use the UnitId to create a deterministic GUID?**

Comment: GUID is not supposed to be created "based on some value". If you need, you can make HASH based on that value but don't call it `guid` then. Map table suggested by @Lucasz is the way to do this on test env, as well as on prod env.

Comment: Be very careful doing this. There are some very serious performance problems if this becomes your clustered index. https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/guids-as-primary-keys-andor-the-clustering-key/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stop thinking about the problem from a ["string" perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52070807/15498). an `int` is made up of 4 bytes. A `uniqueidentifier` is made up of 16 bytes. you can easily take 12 fixed bytes and append the four bytes from an `int` to the end of those, and get a solution that works for all `int` values:

```
declare @Unit table
(
UniqueColumn UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID(),
Characters VARCHAR(10),
IntegerId int
)

-- Add *3* data rows
INSERT INTO @Unit(Characters, IntegerId) VALUES ('abc', 1111),('def', 2222),('ghi',-17)

-- Deterministically creates a uniqueidentifier value out of an integer value. 
DECLARE @GuidPrefix binary(12) = 0xefbeadde0000000000000000
UPDATE @Unit 
    SET UniqueColumn = CONVERT(uniqueidentifier,@GuidPrefix + CONVERT(binary(4),IntegerId))

-- Check the result
SELECT * FROM @Unit
```

Result:

```
UniqueColumn                         Characters IntegerId
------------------------------------ ---------- -----------
DEADBEEF-0000-0000-0000-000000000457 abc        1111
DEADBEEF-0000-0000-0000-0000000008AE def        2222
DEADBEEF-0000-0000-0000-0000FFFFFFEF ghi        -17
```

(For various reasons, we have to provide the first four bytes in a different order than the one that is used by default when displaying a `uniqueidentifier` as a string, which is why if we want to display `DEADBEEF`, we had to start our binary as `efbeadde`)

Also, of course, insert usual warnings that if you're creating guids/uniqueidentifiers but not using one of the prescribed methods for generating them, then you cannot assume any of the usual guarantees about uniqueness.

Comment: This is a great answer, and I accept it. For me, in my application, the use of "verbatim" id values in the GUID is quite convenient, and I will implement my solution. But again, this is for test data purposes only!

Answer (score 6):

You could create keymap table:

```
CREATE TABLE tab_map(id_old INT PRIMARY KEY, guid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER);

INSERT INTO tab_map(id_old, guid)
SELECT id, NEWID()
FROM src_table;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=1fb9f974ab072ee763c62a2c14558bcb)**

After that you could use simple query or wrap with a function:

```
SELECT guid
FROM tab_map
WHERE id_old = ?
```

Comment: While this is somewhat helpful, it misses my main point - having deterministic GUID's. Remember this is for test data only, where I want to prove that my queries still work as expected. For production, we will start over with completely fresh data.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up solving this for myself. Here's my solution for future reference:

I create a prefix part of the GUID in the form of `deadbeef-0000-0000-0000-`, then append a "stringified", zero-padded version of the Id column's integer value to it, like `000000000001`, wich results in

```
DEADBEEF-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
```

in this example.

Here's the SQL command for this action on a whole table:

```
-- Deterministically creates a uniqueidentifier value out of an integer value. 
DECLARE @GuidPrefix nvarchar(max) = N'deadbeef-0000-0000-0000-';  -- without the last 12 digits
UPDATE Unit 
    SET UniqueColumn = 
    (SELECT @GuidPrefix + RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(IntegerId AS NVARCHAR (12)), 12 ) AS NUMBER_CONVERTED)
```

**Warnings:**

- This implementation works only for positive int values (which are up
  to 2147483647 max)
- This is only intended for test data! Use is
  strongly discouraged for production data!

And here's a complete working example:

```
-- Create an example table with random GUID's
CREATE TABLE Unit
(
UniqueColumn UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWID(),
Characters VARCHAR(10),
IntegerId int
)

-- Add 2 data rows
INSERT INTO Unit(Characters, IntegerId) VALUES ('abc', 1111)
INSERT INTO Unit(Characters, IntegerId) VALUES ('def', 2222)

-- Deterministically creates a uniqueidentifier value out of an integer value. 
DECLARE @GuidPrefix nvarchar(max) = N'deadbeef-0000-0000-0000-';  -- without the last 12 digits
UPDATE Unit 
    SET UniqueColumn = 
    (SELECT @GuidPrefix + RIGHT('000000000000' + CAST(IntegerId AS NVARCHAR (12)), 12 ) AS NUMBER_CONVERTED)

-- Check the result
SELECT * FROM Unit
```

Result:

```
UniqueColumn                            Characters IntegerId
--------------------------------------- ---------- ---------
DEADBEEF-0000-0000-0000-000000001111    abc        1111
DEADBEEF-0000-0000-0000-000000002222    def        2222
```